# create automated email for all abandoned purchases

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop-1.5

I just need a logic flow on how to track abandoned purchases by the customers so that I can capture it and email to admin on PrestaShop.

My store is on PrestaShop 1.5.5.0.

Please suggest / Guide.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

so you want to send email only to registered customers when they abandon their shopping cart for XX hours/days. This is fairly easy to achieve but you still need to create a custom module to achieve this result.

In your admin panel go to **customers -> shopping carts**

There you can see all the shopping carts ever made and ( if registered customers made them ) customer info too. In database you need to look at a table named **cart** where you can get all the relevant data for your custom module. ( creation date, updated date, id_customer and so on )

Im happy to help if you need some further help.

BR's

Comment: No, I want to send email only to my admin(site owner) if any user (registered or Guest) abandoned purchases with the details(user + Product). Any suggestion please?

Comment: well the logic is same but instead it will send a email to your admin or rather notify him in a admin panel when certain time passes from creation of a cart